# My python code consist of a dictionary ,The code is giving key error :7. can anyone help me understand what i am doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

> dictionary with key-value pairs.I am getting key error:7 . can anyone help me with my code

```
s= {'0':0,'1':0,'2':0,'3':0,'4':0,'5':0,'6':0,'7':0,'8':0,'9':0

x=input()
y=list(x)
for i in y:
    if i=='0':
        s[0]+=1
    elif i=='1':
        s[1]+=1
    elif i=='2':
        s[2]+=1
    elif i=='3':
        s[3]+=1
    elif i=='4':
        s[4]+=1
    elif i=='5':
        s[5]+=1
    elif i=='6':
        s[6]+=1
    elif i=='7': 
        s[7]+=1
    elif i=='8':
        s[8]+=1
    elif i=='9':
        s[9]+=1
for i in s:
    print(i,s[i])
```

> // print the count of each number according to input

Comment: What is the reason for something like that? Can't you simply have `s[i] += 1` inside the loop? What's with the big `if ... elif` construct? And you should not need to create a list of the input, you should be able to iterate over each character in a string.

Comment: As for your error, what type is the key in the dictionary `s`? Are they `int`? No? Then why are you using `int` keys to access the elements of the dictionary?

Comment: I have to print the count for  all the numbers from 0 to 9 and not only those which are there inside the list

Comment: Your dict keys are in `str` and you are calling `s[2]` where `2` is `int`. It should be `s['2']`

Comment: Lets say `i == '2'`, then what is the difference between doing `s['2'] += 1` and `s[i] += 1`? None. That's why you can do plain `s[i] += 1` without all those conditions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i got it bro,mistake with me using int as keys ...but how do we sort them while printing

Comment: And ***don't*** update your question to "correct" it. That makes answers and comments worthless.

Comment: got it @Someprogrammerdude. but i couldn't get your syntax of s[i]+=1. How will i compare with every different value?

Comment: You don't need to test it, that's the point. [See here for an example](https://ideone.com/wD8SXa).

Comment: thanks for help and suggestions @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue:

```
for i in y:
    if i=='0':
        s['0']+=1
    elif i=='1':
        s['1']+=1
```

Issue is with the dict key. It needs to be quoted like above`(s['0'],s['1'])`.

Output will be like below:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ python3 t1.py

1234
x: 1234
y: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
5 0
7 0
6 0
1 1
0 0
3 1
2 1
8 0
9 0
4 1
```

## To sort:

```
import collections
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(s.items()))
for k, v in od.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: ya , i got it . can you please tell me how to sort it and then print

Comment: @AmitDhanik Let me know if it is what you wanted?

Comment: yes mayank i got it . But i did for i in sorted(s): print (i,s[i]) and it is giving me the correct result.Is it good to use this way?